# Why manually writing into stderr suppress other exceptions' error massage in python?

Tags: python, exception, io, stderr

I figured out that after I try to manually write something into the `stderr` file, no error message will be appear in the shell.

```py
>>> f = open(2, 'w')
>>> f.write('hello\n')
hello
6
>>> f.close()
>>> raise Exception
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 1/0
>>>
```

Why it happens?

Comment: You have closed the `stderr` handle with `f.close()`?

Comment: For contrast, try `f = open(2, 'w', closefd=False)`

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Even if I don't close the `stderr` it will suppress error messages.

Comment: When your process starts, stderr is opened for you. By calling `open(2, 'w')` you merely wrap the file descriptor in a file object. But when you call `close()` it closes the underlying file descriptor unless you open it with `closefd=False`

Comment: No, it is only the closing of stderr that suppresses error messages.